# How to convert to []reflect.Value() to []string?

Tags: go

I'm trying to map my map keys into a slice. I found this solution which seems to be working great.

```golang
func main() {
  newMap := map[string]bool{
    "a": true,
    "b": true,
    "c": true,
  }

  mappedToSlice := reflect.ValueOf(newMap).MapKeys()

  var convertToSliceString []string
  _ = convertToSliceString
}
```

This `reflect.ValueOf(newMap).MapKeys()` seems to be working on mapping the keys to a slice. But, the problem is that it returns a value with a type of `[]reflect.Value`. Meanwhile, I wanna store it in a type of `[]string` (or any other slice type) just like on the `convertToSliceString` variable.

Is there any way to do it? I've tried using `interface` and looking for other methods but no one seems to be able to convert it.

Comment: You'll have to iterate over each value and convert it to `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop to assign the value strings to a slice:

```
mappedToSlice := reflect.ValueOf(newMap).MapKeys()
convertToSliceString := make([]string, len(mappedToSlice))
for i, v := range mappedToSlice {
    convertToSliceString[i] = v.Interface().(string)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I have a question tho. I just tried using `v.String()` instead of `v.Interface().(string)`, and both of the gave me the same results. Is there any difference on using them?

Comment: `v.Interface().(string)` panics when the value is not a string. `v.String()`  returns `<T value>` where T is the name of the type when v's kind is not string.